# Highlighting Rows with CF based on cell with sequencial values

Tags: excel, rows, highlight

I can't seem to nail this down. Using Excel 2010 I've got a column (B) with various 'signals' that each have a sequential number. i.e. 'IP1', IP2', IP3', 'FLOW1', 'FLOW2', 'GV1', 'GV2", and so on... I'm trying to highlight the entire row based on the type of signal (IP, FLOW, GV, etc.) ignoring the sequential value.

Using the CF highlight rule for "text that Contains" only highlights the individual cell. Using this formula to highlight the entire row: =$B2="IP" does not give desired results because all my values have a number as well. I've also tried wildcards: =$B2="IP?" and =$B2="IP*" with no luck.

Is there a way to do this without creating one rule for each sequential signal? I'd even settle for something like this: =$B2="IP1","IP2","IP3" but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm a newby at Excel and know I'm dancing all around the answer here. I don't see this particular problem in other posts...

Comment: How large do the increments go? Do they stay single digits or do they go into double or triple digits (e.g. FLOW12, FLOW 213) ?

Comment: Modified tags as this question seems to be about Excel, not cfml (ColdFusion Markup Language).

Comment: Sorry Jeeped, forgot to answer your question... The signals do go into double digits. I noticed this matters when I filter the spreadsheet by signal type. IP10, IP11 etc. will be listed before IP2, IP3 and so on... The COUNTIF formula below did work to highlight the rows, but is there a better formula that will treat the wildcards as sequential numbers?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional formatting formulas you're looking for will either be `COUNTIF` with wildcards or `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(`.  Personally I prefer the `COUNTIF` route, but here's both for your perusal:

```
=COUNTIF($B2,"IP*")>0
=COUNTIF($B2,"FLOW*")>0
=COUNTIF($B2,"GV*")>0

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("IP",$B2))
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FLOW",$B2))
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GV",$B2))
```

Comment: DOH! Yes, I had also tried COUNTIF but with the wrong format. That solved it. Thank you Tigeravatar!...